# How are paths to files and folders constructed in OS X?

Tags: macos, filesystem, file, path

I need to indicate a right file path to read a `.csv` file into R on OS X, but how can I find where the file is stored? Looking at Excel files, the file path starts at `users/…`, but there is no indication of a disk or something.

Answer (score 6):

**There's no disk letter in OS X unlike Windows.**

The mount point for disks is usually /Volumes. For example, files on a flash drive with the name `FLASHDRIVE` will be located in `/Volumes/FLASHDRIVE/`.

The startup disk is the root, `/`. Therefore, the Users folder is `/Users`. No drive letter is prepended to this.

Answer (score 3):

You can right click the file and "Get Info". The path is written right there. Alternatively you could e.g. drag the file into a terminal window to see the path..